# Load csv data into posgreSQL using Python

Tags: python, csv, psycopg2

I am new to the world of python and have some problems loading data from a csv files unto postgresql.

I have successfully connected to my database from python and created my table. But when I go to load the data from the csv file into the created table in postgresql, I get nothing on the table when I use either the insert function or or copy function and commit.

```
cur.execute('''COPY my_schema.sheet(id, length, width, change_d, change_h,change_t, change_a, name) 
FROM '/private/tmp/data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;''')
dbase.commit()
```

I am not sure what I am missing, can anyone please help with this or advise a better way to load csv data using python script

Comment: Does it works if you execute the same sql query from the psql shell?
If fails even without python, then you know, that the issue is the query and not the python code.

Comment: it works fine with sql to now. It is all good, thanks gelondia

Comment: So you want to say, you don't need an answer to the question anymore?

What was the problem?